# What are the usage differences between size_t and off_t?

Tags: c++, linux

Other than the size of the values that each type can hold, what are the main differences in **usage** between `size_t` and `off_t`? Is it just a convention that `size_t` types are used for absolute sizes and `off_t` types are used for offsets? Or does it go deeper than that?

I am writing a wrapper class to enable the writing of large files using `mmap` and I want to know what the best types are to use for their arguments. Given that I want to write to files > 4GB, I'm tempted to use size_t for everything, but is that the best practice? (or should I be using some `off64_t` types for certain functions?)

For example, should my `writeAt` function be declared as:

```
MMapWriter::writeAt(off64_t offset, const void* src, size_t size)
```

or

```
MMapWriter::writeAt(size_t offset, const void* src, size_t size)
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`size_t` is for objects, `off_t` is for files.

`mmap` merges the two concepts, pretty much by definition. Personally I think I'd use `size_t`, since no matter what else it is, a mapped file is also an array in (virtual) memory.

`size_t` is standard C++, `off_t` is Posix, and `off64_t` is a GNU extension that goes with the functions `fopen64`, `ftello64`, etc. I *think* it should always be the same type as `off_t` on 64 bit GNU systems, but don't bet your company on that without checking.

Should it be relevant, `off_t` is signed whereas `size_t` is unsigned. But the signed counterpart to `size_t` is `ptrdiff_t`, so when you need a signed type it doesn't automatically mean you should use `off_t` or `off64_t`.

Comment: Thanks Steve, this is a great help. I guess I hadn't quite made the link that `mmap` was bridging the two concepts.

Comment: Great answer, but why in the hell do fread() and fwrite() take `size_t` then?

Comment: Notice that there is also ssize_t as a signed counterpart of size_t.

Comment: @NikReiman: I think `fread` takes `size_t` because the "most important fact" about the size is how it relates to the buffer. Even if files can be bigger than in-memory objects on your system, the size of the objects read/written by fread/fwrite is limited to memory. But the C standard doesn't handle large files all that well: `fseek` uses `long` for the offset, which Posix considers unsatisfactory and therefore introduces `fseeko` and `off_t`. Maybe it's just because the C standard originally envisaged that `long` would always be the biggest integer type, but then Microsoft argued otherwise.

Comment: Don't use `off64_t` or 64-bit file functions explicitly; adding `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to `CFLAGS` will automatically change all `off_t` to `off64_t` on GNU systems while maintaining compatibility with systems that don't understand `off64_t`.

Comment: re: "I think it should always be the same type as off_t on 64 bit GNU systems" --  On Ubuntu 64-bit, compiling for 32-bit with `gcc -m32 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 ...` I get sizeof(off_t) = 8 and sizeof(size_t) = 4.   So while your 64-bit statement is true, they can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: @DanielWiddis: yeah, I'd consider `gcc -m32` to be (a compiler for) a 32-bit system. Doesn't matter whether the compiler is *running* on a 64-bit system or a ZX Spectrum, and doesn't matter whether the code it spits out is eventually run on a true 32-bit chip, a 64-bit chip in x86 mode, or a ZX Spectrum emulating an i386, or all three! So, on 32-bit systems we expect `size_t` is size 4, and `off_t` is either 4 or 8. But implementations are entitled to keep us entertained by surprising us sometimes.

Comment: Indeed! My current system is entertaining me by telling me I logged in 28 minutes in the future, for reasons I can't figure out other than MT-unsafe weirdness. :)

Answer (score 15):

`size_t` is part of the C++ (and C) standards, and refers to the type of a `sizeof` expression.  `off_t` is defined by the Posix standard, and refers to the size of a file.

Comment: So using `off_t`is non portable? Or do C/C++ standard themselves adhere to the posix standard.

Comment: @Als: The Posix libraries are a set of extensions to the C (and C++) standard. Among the things they add are `off_t` and the file functions that use it, like `lseek`. So no, C/C++ do not adhere to Posix. Anyway Posix is a specification for an operating system rather than just one programming language: as well as libraries it includes for example a shell and shell utilities, which are beyond the scope of the C standard (If you like, Posix picks up where the standard definition of `system` leaves off).

Comment: And using `off_t` "is portable" if you're already using `mmap`, also a Posix function. It's portable Posix code, it's not portable C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Good rule of thumb for this scenario. Use whatever function signature that results in you using the least amount of explicit casting, be it c style or c++ style. If you have to cast, c++ style is safer as it is more limited in the types of cast it can do.

The benefit of this is if you port to a platform where the types don't match up (whether it be a signed, size or endianness issue etc.), you should catch most of the bugs at compile time, rather than at runtime. Casting is the sledgehammer approach for squeezing a triangular shaped object into a round hole (more or less your telling the compiler to keep quiet, I know what I'm doing).

Trying to find casting issues at runtime can be a pain as it can be hard to reproduce. It's better to find issues at compile-time rather than runtime. The compiler is your friend.