# How to find out how much space to allocate a char array

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a program that takes a file given by the user and proceeds to read it. However, I would also like to use as little memory as possible and therefore do not want to allocate 100000 chars to the array unless it is completely necessary. Here is the code I currently have to read the file.

```c
char    *read_input(const char *file)
{
    int         fd;
    int         read_stat;
    int         i;
    char        tmp[1000000];
    char        buffer[1];

    i = 0;
    if ((fd = open(file, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
        printf("Error");

    while ((read_stat = read(fd, buffer, 1)))
    {
        tmp[i++] = buffer[0];
        if (i > 1000000)
            printf("Error");
    }
    tmp[i] = '\0';
    if (close(fd) == -1)
        printf("Error");
    return (ft_strdup(tmp));
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this. The traditional way is to dynamically allocate a pointer to point to each line and memory for each individual line. The scheme is quite simple. Allocate some initial number of pointers in `read_input`, continually read each line, allocating storage for each line and assigning the address for the block of memory to the next available pointer, keeping track of the number of pointers used, reallocating the number of pointers as required, and calling `realloc` one final time at the end of the function to size the number of pointers allocated to exactly the number needed.

When you digest the scheme, it basically allocates no more memory than absolutely necessary to hold the file (+one pointer per-line). It is about as memory-efficient as you can get for reading a file of unknown size containing lines of unknown length.

With that said, there are a few adjustments to make to `read_input`. Generally the file is opened in the calling function (`main()` here) and a file stream pointer (or file descriptor) passed to `read_input` as a parameter. You should also pass a pointer to `size_t` to `read_input` as a second parameter, and update the pointer with the number of lines read in `read_input` so that value is available back in the caller.

(you could also allocate one additional pointer at the end to serve as a *sentinel* `NULL` allowing you to determine the number of lines read without passing a pointer to `size_t`)

You will return a *pointer to pointer to char* from `read_input` (e.g. `char**` instead of `char*`) making all lines available to the calling function.

To handle file operations, you are free to use file descriptors and the low level `read`/`write` functions, but C has the file stream functions available to make the job of reading/handling text files a bit easier. (e.g. reading with `fgets`, or POSIX `getline` as is done below)

Putting all that together, you could do something like the following that will read the file given as the first argument (or from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided). It will read a file of any size with lines of any length until the end of the file is reached (unless memory is exhausted before the end of the file is reached)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXPTRS 32

char **read_input (FILE *fp, size_t *ndx)
{
    size_t maxp = MAXPTRS,  /* initial number of pointers */
        n = 0;              /* initial memory for line (0, getline decides) */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;       /* number of chars read by getline */
    char *line = NULL,      /* buffer to read each line */
        **lines = NULL;     /* pointer to pointer to all stored lines */
    *ndx = 0;               /* zero index pointer passed from caller */

    if (!(lines = calloc (maxp, sizeof *lines))) { /* allocate pointers */
        fprintf (stderr, "read_input: memory exhausted.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* read each line (into line) */
    while ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, fp)) != -1) {
        if (nchr && line[nchr - 1] == '\n') /* chk/trim trailing '\n' */
            line[--nchr] = 0;
        lines[*ndx] = strdup (line); /* duplicate line (belongs to getline) */
        if (++(*ndx) == maxp) {      /* check if reallocation of ptrs req'd */
            void *tmp = realloc (lines, sizeof *lines * maxp * 2);
            if (!tmp) {     /* if realloc fails, bail */
                fprintf (stderr, "read_input: memory exhausted - realloc.\n");
                goto memlimit;
            }
            lines = tmp;    /* assign reallocted block to lines */
            /* zero all new memory (optional) */
            memset (lines + maxp, 0, maxp * sizeof *lines);
            maxp *= 2;      /* increment number of allocated pointers */
        }
    }
    /* final realloc to reduce to exact number of pointers */
    void *tmp = realloc (lines, *ndx * sizeof *lines);
    if (tmp)
        lines = tmp;

    if (*ndx == 0) {  /* protect against realloc returning NULL or a */
        free (lines); /* pointer suitable to be passed to free ambiguity */
        lines = NULL;
    }
    memlimit:;              /* label for goto */

    free (line);            /* free line (it belongs to getline) */

    return lines;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t n = 0;           /* number of lines read by read_input */
    char **lines = NULL;    /* ptr to ptr to char for lines returned */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* call read_input/validate return */
    if (!(lines = read_input (fp, &n)) || n == 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: read_input failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);       /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {    /* iterate over each line */
        printf ("line[%3zu] : %s\n", i, lines[i]);
        free (lines[i]);                /* free memory for line */
    }
    free (lines);                       /* free pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getline_read_input <../dat/captnjack.txt
line[  0] : This is a tale
line[  1] : Of Captain Jack Sparrow
line[  2] : A Pirate So Brave
line[  3] : On the Seven Seas.
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block of memory, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/getline_read_input <../dat/captnjack.txt
==20213== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20213== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20213== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20213== Command: ./bin/getline_read_input
==20213==
line[  0] : This is a tale
line[  1] : Of Captain Jack Sparrow
line[  2] : A Pirate So Brave
line[  3] : On the Seven Seas.
==20213==
==20213== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20213==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20213==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 484 bytes allocated
==20213==
==20213== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==20213==
==20213== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20213== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Oops `*nxp` part looks good.  Still suggest `if (tmp || *nxp == 0) lines = tmp;`  `*alloc(0)` is troublesome.

Comment: No.  realloc(ptr, 0) may return not-`NULL`.  IMO, `read_input ()` should start with `*ndx = 0;   lines = NULL` and then first allocate after something is read.  Then in the end only a final reallocate if `*ndx > 0`.

Comment: I get it, an explicit set of `lines = NULL` on the event `*ndx == 0` after a failed read -- got it. (the light bulb came on...)

Comment: Yes there are some pesky no-read and error cases to consider.  Good luck GTG.

Comment: @chux I added a separate `if (*ndx == 0)` block to resolve the ambiguity in return of *either* `NULL` or a pointer suitable of being passed to `free` from `realloc` in the event `*ndx == 0` after a failed call to `getline` on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the size of the file using stat() and based on that dynamically allocate memory to tmp. Something like -

```
    struct stat st;
    off_t filesize;

    if (stat(filename, &st) == 0)
       filesize = st.st_size;
```

Once you get filesize, allocate that much memory to tmp.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
struct stat st;
stat(filename, &st);
int size = st.st_size;
printf("size = %d\n", size);
```

It should give you the number of caraters read in `size`.

Nicolas

Comment: J'ai été devancé xD (PS: c'est Tom)

Comment: Rip la norme @YaatSuka ahaha

Comment: `st.st_size` is type `off_t`.   `off_t` is some _signed_ type.  To not truncate with `int size = st.st_size`, used a wide type. `printf("size = %lld\n", (long long) st.st_size);`  [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10634629/2410359)

Answer (score 0):

You can use malloc , Something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char *read_input(const char *file) {
   int  fd;

   char *buffer;

   if ((fd = open(file, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
      printf("Error");

   int size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
   lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
   buffer = (char*)malloc(size+1);
   read(fd, buffer, size);
   close(fd);

   return buffer;
}


int main() {

 char *r = read_input("test.txt");
 //printf("%s\n",r);
 free(r);

 return 0;
```

}

Comment: You allocate +1 byte intended for nul-terminator - but never assign it... So buffer is not nul-terminated and cannot be safely used - since the size of the buffer is not returned

Comment: `lseek()` returns type `off_t`.  A value of that type may far exceed `int` and even `size_t`.  Robust code would insure the value passed to `malloc()` was  not truncated with `int` and in `size_t` range.